# Does immutable types work for this caching issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, immutability

I sometimes have a problem where I get an object from the cache and need to change some properties of it, that didnt exist when I put the object into the Cache.

Lets say I have a class

```
public void class Person
{
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public bool HasNotifications { get; set; }
}
```

`FirstName` and `LastName` are stored in the Database. When the object is fetched from the Database it is put into the cache with HasNotifications being false.

The Person object might be used in several parts of the application and `HasNotifications` will be set to different values depending on the part of the application.

Changing `HasNotifications` changes the object in the cache and the value is not predictable anymore.

This example seems a bit contrieved because there are easy ways to avoid the problem. The application I work on has the issue, because sometimes it is not obvious that the object you work on is retrieved from the Cache.

If I used a immutable version of `Person` would that avoid the problem? Is this a usecase Immutability is supposed to handle?

Answer (score 0):

Caching should be used for objects that are unlikely to change all that frequently. It sounds like the majority of your object stays the same, aside from HasNotifications? If so, I would consider a means to remove this logic from the cached object if possible.